# What is necessary cleanup for CInternetSession

Tags: c++, mfc

The MSDN documentation for `CInternetSession::Close()` only says

> Call this member function when your application has finished using the `CInternetSession` object.
>
> [MSDN for CInternetSession::Close](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tya7fy2.aspx)

For the `CHttpConnection` object returned by `CInternetSession::GetHttpConnection()`, and the `CHttpFile` object returned by `CHttpConnection::OpenRequest()`, do these objects have to be manually closed and deleted?

I cannot find the documentation for `CHttpConnection::Close()` on MSDN, and `CHttpFile` inherits its `Close()` method from `CInternetFile`; the documentation for which is similarly unhelpful:

> Closes a `CInternetFile` and frees any of its resources.
>
> (sorry, I can't have three links)

My gut assumption would be that since `CInternetSession::GetHttpConnection()` and `CHttpConnection::OpenRequest()` return pointers, and since the MSDN for `CHttpConnection` says

> You never create a `CHttpConnection` object directly; rather, call `CInternetSession::GetHttpConnection`, which creates the `CHttpConnection` object and returns a pointer to it.
>
> (sorry, I can't have three links)

that `CInternetSession` internally stores a reference to the `CHttpConnection` that it generated and cleans up that object when `CInternetSession::Close()` is called. This is supported by [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yh4zs9e.aspx), which does not mention any cleanup for the connection object, and states

> Dispose of the CInternetSession object --> Automatically cleans up open file handles and connections.

## Short question

Is this necessary:

```
CInternetSession session(...);
CHttpConnection * connection = session.GetHttpConnection(...);
CHttpFile * file = connection->OpenRequest(...);

... Do stuff ...

file->Close();
delete file;

connection->Close();
delete connection;

session.Close();
```

Or is it sufficient to do:

```
CInternetSession session(...);
CHttpConnection * connection = session.GetHttpConnection(...);
CHttpFile * file = connection->OpenRequest(...);

... Do stuff ...

session.Close();
```

### Meta question

If---from the documentation for a library---it is unclear where the responsibility lies for cleaning up resources, what are possible ways to detect resource leaks? I know that Valgrind can be used for memory leaks, but what about file handles and other resources that might be tied up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you don't have to call `Close()`, it gets done by MFC destructors. Ideally the destructor should do all the necessary cleanups.

MFC classes are poorly documented as you noted. WinINet functions have much better documentation:

[MSDN WinINet functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It says for example, `::InternetOpen` handle must be closed with `InternetCloseHandle`. We can look at definition for MFC classes and compare:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\inet.cpp`

```
CInternetSession(){
    ::InternetOpen //WinINet
    ...
}

CInternetSession::Close(){
    ::InternetCloseHandle //WinINet
    ...
}

CInternetSession::~CInternetSession(){
    Close();
}
```

So we don't need to call `internetSession.Close()` because it is done automatically by destructor. Calling it wouldn't hurt though. I guess if `CInternetSession` is declared on heap or something, then we may need to `Close()` because it might take sometime before destructor is called.

In the other example we don't have to call `Close` either, but it doesn't hurt.

```
CHttpFile * file = connection->OpenRequest(...);
file->Close();//I think this is okay but not necessary because we "delete file" in next line
delete file;//calls Close(); and other necessary cleanups
```

Short version:

```
CInternetSession session(...);
CHttpConnection *connection = session.GetHttpConnection(...);
CHttpFile *file = connection->OpenRequest(...);
//... Do stuff ...
delete file;//don't skip
delete connection;//don't skip
//session.Close();//you can skip, this gets called when we exist the function
```

By the way, putting breakpoint on `CInternetSession obj` and stepping in it, should also take you to the MFC file `..\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\inet.cpp`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help. It should be possible to use auto_ptr/unique_ptr to manage the connection and file as well, correct?

Comment: You are welcome David. I am not really sure, I don't think `auto_ptr` will make things easier in this case. In the example above, `file` is being allocated in another function (`OpenRequest`) if there was an easy way to automatically and safely delete it then it would have been implemented by MFC.

Comment: The WinINet classes may have better documentation, yet it's not without its own holes. For example, after 20 years the `lpszProxy` parameter on [InternetOpenUrlA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetopena) is still "TBD". :-)